# Why does hypergranulation prevent the epithelialization of a wound?

Tags: injury, healing

I recently read about how does a wound heals. I read that when the granulation tissue protrudes out of the wound bed (proud flesh), the epithelialization cannot occur because the protruding proud flesh is in the way.

But I don't really understand why. Keratinocytes migrate on the surface of the granulation tissue. Even if it bulges out they should follow the geometry of it, shouldn't they? Otherwise I think none of our wounds would heal...